# Concatenating types in DCGs

Tags: prolog, concatenation, dcg

I am attempting to use prolog to develop a simple DCG for a musical context.

I have defined musical notes in the following way:

```
note(ton) --> [a];[d];[f].
note(sup) --> [b];[e];[g].
etc.
```

The 'ton' and 'sup' arguments above relate to which chord the note belongs to. The notes a, d, and f belong to the **ton**ic chord and the notes b, e, and g belong to the **sup**ertonic chord (in the key of D major).

Now, I want to introduce a further 'note' symbol which takes two arguments - one for the chord and one for the note duration. For example,

```
note(X,q) --> note(X),[2].
```

My problem lies in the fact that note(X),[2] is a list [a,2].
I need it in the form [a2].

It is possible to get around this problem by not using the variable X:

```
note(ton) --> [a];[d];[f].
note(ton,q) --> [a2];[d2];[f2].
```

But since there are seven different chords and seven different note lengths in my representation, this would involve a lot of unnecessary (i think) code.

I'm unsure how to concatenate note(X) and the integer 2, and I'm also unsure where this should be done. Is it possible to concatenate things on the right hand side of a rewrite rule?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog has [atomic_list_concat/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/2).  You could run your original code and then run your resulting atom list through this predicate to get a single atom as output:

```
?- X=ton, phrase(note(X, q), ListOut), atomic_list_concat(ListOut, Atom).
Atom = a2 ;
Atom = d2 ;
Atom = f2.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This is exactly what I'm looking for. However, at the moment I can only get the correct response by loading my grammar and running your suggested code from the ?- prompt.

I'm wondering how I could implement the same thing within the grammar, so that a note can be represented as a, or a2 ...

Sorry If this is unclear.

Comment: so you want a new grammar production that calls note?  note(X, q) --> {phrase(note(X), ListOut), atomic_list_concat(ListOut, Atom)}, [Atom].

Comment: or make a new grammar rule note_q(X) --> {phrase(note(X), ListOut), atomic_list_concat(ListOut, Atom)}, [Atom].  sorry if I am not elucidating what you *should* do, just what you could do.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I pretty much had it, I just didn't know about the use of curly brackets on the right hand side of a rewrite rule. Cheers again.